# C++11 outer scope variable declared auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

In C++ where it's available, it's good practice to use `auto` for many variables, in particular those whose type is known but annoying to type out:

```
weird_template_type<int,char>::subtype::recursive_subtype some_function() {
    // ...
}
// ...
auto val = some_function();
```

It's also good to use micro-scopes for RAII objects when that makes sense, e.g. for locking:

```
some_setup_code();
int val;
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mut);
    val = read_shared_memory();
}
do_something(val);
```

Is there a way to mix these two idioms, e.g. when your shared-memory-reading code returns a strange type?

The obvious version doesn't work:

```
auto val;
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mut);
    val = read_shared_memory();
}
do_something(val);
```

This fails at compile time due to an `auto` variable without an initializer.

Similarly, you can't declare the variable inside the scoped block, or else it isn't available later.

The only immediate options I can see are 1. type out the variable declaration explicitly (bleah), or 2. use `auto` with some other expression you know to be of the same type (not an improvement). Is there some other way?

Comment: Maybe `decltype()`?

Comment: `auto val = (lock_guard<mutex>(mut), read_shared_memory()); do_something(val);`

Comment: I want to point out that in most cases opening a new scope in the middle of a "real" scope for locking purposes indicates a design issue. you should consider why this is what you're doing

Comment: @ZivS Why so? It's just the natural conclusion from 1. keep critical sections small, and 2. use RAII. What would be the preferred design?

Comment: It depends on the use case. but in your code- why ins't the lock inside read_shared_memory?

Comment: In my case, the shared memory is a queue passing items to a worker thread, and `read_shared_memory()` is just `queue_.size()`. It doesn't really seem worthwhile to add a separate function here that's two lines long and only called once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, what you're talking about is complex variable initialization. The typical solution is to use a lambda:

```
auto val = [&]() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mut);
    return read_shared_memory();
}();
```

Comment: That's something I've considered doing in the past, but I thought it might be too confusing for future maintainers. How do you know that this is the "typical" solution?

Comment: JS developers would call it an IIFE; it's immediately familiar to me from that context. Unsure how much overlap there is there, but no confusion on my end.

Comment: @KyleStrand: You may still use regular function.Which is more old school but better for re-usability.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that's what I've typically gravitated toward. I do like that the lambda approach avoids a proliferation of `safe_do_some_thing()` functions each invoking non-threadsafe `do_some_thing()` functions, though.

Answer (score 8):

You may consider

```
decltype(read_shared_memory()) val;
{
    lock_guard<mutex> lk(mut);
    val = read_shared_memory();
}
do_something(val);
```

although it is not necessarily less verbose.

Comment: Violates DRY, better solutions exist...do not use. :)

Comment: Violations of DRY aside, this solution requires that the type you're initializing can be default constructed.

Comment: @GManNickG Oh, I agree, it not the cleanest one. But imagine we have more than one variable to set, then lambda would not look nice either. (BTW, personally I like the one **@cpplearner** put the comments. :) )

Answer (score 3):

You may create a helper function for that:

```
int read_shared_int_memory(std::mutex &mut);
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
    return read_shared_memory();
}
```

and then, simply:

```
auto val = read_shared_int_memory(mut);
```